# matplotlib y axis labels disappearing with fontsize change

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to plot the contents of a dataframe.

Using pandas and matplotlib:

```
thedata = {'2013':[0.0,0.0]
          ,'2014':[0.0,0.0]
          ,'2015':[0.0,0.0]
          ,'2016':[1,0.0]
          ,'2017':[0.0,0.0]
          ,'2018':[1,0.0]}

my_df = pd.DataFrame(thedata, index=['Green cars','Red cars'])

    plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
    my_ax = plt.gca()
    my_ax.clear()
    my_ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

    my_df.transpose().plot(kind='bar'
                , stacked=True  
                , ax=my_ax
                ).grid(True,'major','y')

    my_ax.legend(loc=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), frameon=False, ncol=2, fontsize=12 )
    plt.title('All the cars', fontsize = 12 )
    my_ax.set_xticklabels(my_ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation='horizontal', fontsize=12)
#     my_ax.set_yticklabels(my_ax.get_yticklabels(),fontsize=12)
```

[image: The dataframe and the output]

The last line is commented out in order to get the output displayed.  I want to increase the font size of the y axis labels to be the same as the x, but when i un-comment that line and run it, the y axis labels just disappear and nothing is displayed there.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Edit: - create the dataframe; pandas 0.23.0, matplotlib 2.2.2

Comment: Can you make this reproducible by defining the dataframe inside your code and stating which version of matplotlib and pandas you are using? See [mcve].

Comment: Edited post to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face here is that the ticklabels are not actually defined before the figure is drawn.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3,4,2])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You may draw the figure, before accessing those labels

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3,4,2])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

fig.canvas.draw()
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, in order to change the fontsize of the ticklabels, one would rather use

```
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=12)
```

or set the property to the labels, without actually setting the labels' content. E.g. via `setp`

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=12)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Would you please explain why would one rather use tick_params() or setp()?

Comment: If you set the fontsize, both are equally well suited. The difference is that you cannot set *every* property via `tick_params`. So for example, if you want to change the `rotation_mode` of a label, you cannot use `tick_params`. If then you want to change the fontsize and the rotation mode, using a single line with `setp` is preferable. Another argument: When you haven't imported pyplot, you won't do that exactly for use of `setp`. So in that case you can use `tick_params` or the longer variant of using a loop.

Comment: i tried all these methods still not able to set my ticks fontsize. Please someone help me.
https://ibb.co/HTKC9nM